# In redux, are their option for separate store for separate tabs which opened with same react JS web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my React JS app, there is the list of orders in the table with a unique order ID. When I click on one row of the orders table then open a new tab with details of that order and then I store these details in the redux store.

This is working fine.

Now the use-case is supposed I open a new order, it opens a new tab then order details of that order stored in the redux store.
Currently, it overrides old data to new
now if I go to the previous tab of first-order details then order details show of latest order store.

I want a new store for each tab to remove conflicts of redux data.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think Redux keeps the state across different tabs by default, unless you intentionally make it so using eg. `redux-state-sync`.

So, could you be a little bit more specific? What tool did you use?

Comment: @k-wasilewski currently I use redux-persist but actually my issue is when I open multiple tabs then for tab need separate store to get separate data for each order which are open in every tab

Comment: Then you just basically need to NOT use this `redux-persist` for a store you want fresh for every tab..

Comment: @k-wasilewski after removing `redux-persist` , the issue I'm facing will that solves if I open multiple tabs and go to the previous tab redux data should appear of that tab?

Comment: Well each tab should now have its independent redux state..

Answer (score 0):

Each time when you are creating a new order you can create an unique key for the each tab and keep this state in the redux state as a dictionary.

```
{
[tabKey1]: {orderState1},
[tabKey2]: {orderState2}
}
```

You can pass these keys as a query parameter.